# pythonでのwebページのリンク抽出について

Tags: python

クローラーを作ろうと思い、webページのリンクを抽出するコードを欠いていたのですが、
以下の部分で　"Attribute Error 'tuple' object hano attribute find"というエラーが出てしまいます。どうすれば回避できるでしょうか
補足：御助言ありがとうございます。コード全体はこのようになってます。

```
def get_page(page):
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote+1)
    url =  page[start_quote+1 : end_quote]
    return url, end_quote


def all_get_links(page):
    while True:
        url, end_quote = get_page(page)
        if url:
            print(url)
            page = page[end_quote:]
        else:
            break


print(all_get_links(get_page("http://www.yahoo.co.jp/")))
```

Comment: クローラーの実際のコードを載せたほうがより詳細な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: エラーが出るのはほぼ確実に page が tuple だからです（答えになってない）．page がどこで定義されてるか確認して，どういう tuple が入ってるのか調べて，必要に応じた処理をしましょう（アドバイスになってない）．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_pageがtupleを返しているからではないでしょうか?
`get_page`は`(url, end_quote)`のtupleを返しています。
最後の行でget_pageが返したtupleを引数にall_get_linksを呼んでいますが、そうなるとall_get_linksの引数のpageはtupleになってしまい、tupleにfindメソッドがないのでこのようなエラーが出ています。

このエラーは`tupleにはfindという属性がありません`という意味です。

追記: 最後の行のget_pageの引数が`http://www.yahoo.co.jp/`なのでpage.findは`<a href=`という文字列を**見つけられません**。(`http://www.yahoo.co.jp/`の中に`<a href=`という文字列は含まれていない) そのため返ってくるtupleは必ず`(None, 0)`になってしまいます。これを回避するためにはget_pageに渡す文字列には、きちんとした a tag が含まれるようにしてください。

追記2:
下記のような感じにするのはいかがでしょうか?

```
def get_page(page):
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote+1)
    url =  page[start_quote+1 : end_quote]
    print(url)
    return page[end_quote:]

def all_get_links(page):
   while True:
        page = get_page(page)
        if page == None:
            break

page = '<a href="http://rebuild.fm">Rebuild.fm</a>'
all_get_links(page) # http://rebuild.fm と表示される
```

このやり方だとget_pageは文字列かNoneを返すようになります。Noneを返した場合、すぐにbreakして、whileから抜けるのでエラーにはなりません。Noneではない場合は必ず文字列を返すので、最初のようなエラーは起こりません。

他のやり方として、html.parserのHTMLParserクラスを継承して使うのがいいと思います。
例としては下記のような感じでしょうか

[20.2. html.parser— HTML および XHTML のシンプルなパーサー — Python 3.4.3 ドキュメント](http://docs.python.jp/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs_dict = dict(attrs)
        if tag == "a":
            print(attrs_dict["href"]) #hrefの内容を表示
```

Comment: 御助言ありがとうございます。練習のために、今のやり方のままクローラーを作って行きたいと思うのですが、どうすればタプル形式で返さずにコードを実行できるでしょうか。

Comment: 追記2 としてtupleを返さないやり方を追加しました。

Comment: おっしゃるとおりにしてみたら成功しました。丁寧に御助言いただき、ありがとうございました。後学のために伺いたいのですが、このコードはUdacityというプログラミング学習サイトで学んだもので、このコードで成功した人もいる様なのですが、なぜ私はエラーを出してしまったのでしょうか？pythonのバージョンの違いが原因でしょうか

Answer (score 0):

最近、あまり使っていないのですが、昔、HTMLパーシングには、[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)をよく使っていました。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
links = []
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if hasattr(link, "href"):
        links.append(link.attrs.get("href"))
```